# Gnome: Make system text copyable

Tags: gnome, gtk, copy-paste

Here I use "system text" to refer to the text displayed in the GTK widgets (labels, menus, dialogs etc.)

I would like to be able to highlight and copy any system text. I am using a locale with a non-roman script that I am not fluent in, and I would like to be able to copy menu items, and paste them into a dictionary.

Has anyone ever heard of something that can add that functionality to the GTK libs?

Comment: seems like it'd be very difficult, but you could probably hack something together in the sources and rebuild gtk+.